# were already developed vs had already been developed

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

In [a previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267729/a-matter-of-style-or-a-necessity-to-use-past-simple-in-this-text), I got an answer that says that you can't write "*the song had already been well rehearsed*" because once it is well rehearsed you don't need to rehearse the song.

Would it be the same with develop? Can we say, "*the song had already been developed*", as once a song is developed it is for ever, it should work like rehearsed?

Comment: _Once it is rehearsed it is for ever_ doesn't make sense to me. Each singer or group intending to perform a song normally has to rehearse for that performance. "The first work in the programme had already been rehearsed, so this time we concentrated on the second one."

Comment: You may have misunderstood something you were told previously. There's nothing remotely wrong with saying something like *As most of the songs **had already been well-rehearsed**, we didn't need to practice them*. I will admit that *As most of the songs **had already been good**, we didn't need to revise them* is at least *slightly* "odd / awkward" (because "good" isn't a past participle), but I don't think that necessarily implies it's syntactically invalid.

Comment: So why in my example it was not the past perfect   The song had  already  been well rehearsed before entering the studio . They had played extensively live .

Comment: Where in that previous question did someone say you cannot say, "*the song had already been well rehearsed*"? If someone said that, I disagree. That sentence is fine. Even if you have rehearsed something well, you can continue to rehearse it as often as you like.